# short or simple solution for getting the value for months in a combo box

Tags: vb.net, winforms, loops, combobox

Good day. Anyone can help me with this problem. I have two combo box 1.) for month 2.) for year. I have a code here for months. And I want it to make simple like a loop, Just like getting a year from 2000 to 2015 in the year combo box. Any solutions, suggestions...?

```
  ' I've tried this. but it shows 01-12 numbers in a combobox not January to December
    For i As Integer = 1 To Date.Now.Month
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(i)
    Next
```

For the rest of the code......

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ValueComboxformonth()

    For i As Integer = 2000 To Date.Now.Year
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(i)
    Next
    ' I want my month combo box have a solution like the above for loop
    ' I've tried this. but it shows 01-12 numbers in a combobox not January to December
    'For i As Integer = 1 To Date.Now.Month
    '    ComboBox1.Items.Add(i)
    'Next

End Sub
Private Sub ValueComboxformonth()
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(New forMonthlist("January", "01"))
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(New forMonthlist("February", "02"))
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(New forMonthlist("March", "03"))
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(New forMonthlist("April", "04"))
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(New forMonthlist("May", "05"))
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(New forMonthlist("June", "06"))
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(New forMonthlist("July", "07"))
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(New forMonthlist("August", "08"))
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(New forMonthlist("September", "09"))
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(New forMonthlist("October", "10"))
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(New forMonthlist("November", "11"))
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(New forMonthlist("December", "12"))
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim nMonthStart As forMonthlist = CType(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, forMonthlist)
End Sub
  End Class
```

For the forMonthlist....

```
Public Class forMonthlist
Private mText As String
Private mValue As String

Public Sub New(ByVal pText As String, ByVal pValue As String)
    mText = pText
    mValue = pValue
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property Text() As String
    Get
        Return mText
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property Value() As String
    Get
        Return mValue
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return mText
End Function
End Class
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DateTimeFomatInfo.GetMonthName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getmonthname(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim formatInfo = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo
For i As Integer = 1 To Date.Today.Month
    Dim monthName = formatInfo.GetMonthName(i)
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(monthName)
Next
```

If you  have a month-name and you want it's integer-value you can parse it to a `DateTime`:

```
Dim month As Int32 = Date.ParseExact("July", "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month
```

If you don't want localized names you could use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: How do I get the value of July which is 07 if I select the month of july. Thanks

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter. Sorry I didn't specify it in the question.

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter. It work. But it resulted 7 not 07. Dim month As Int32 = Date.ParseExact(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month

Comment: If you want `07` it is a `string`, so use `ToString` with the appropriate format: `Dim result = month.ToString("D2")` Read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#DFormatString

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

As an option you can use [`DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames(v=vs.110).aspx) to find month names for a culture:

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture _
                             .DateTimeFormat.MonthNames() _
                             .Where(Function(x) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)) _
                             .Select(Function(x, i) _
                                 New With {.Name = x, .Value = (i + 1).ToString("D2")}) _
                             .ToList()
Me.ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
Me.ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Value"
```

To find the value of selected month you can simply use `SelectedValue`:

```
MessageBox.Show(ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString())
'It shows 07 for example for July
```

**Note**

- Some cultures have 13 months, so `DateTimeFormat.MonthNames` returns an array with 13 month. For a 12 month calendar, the 13th element of array is empty string, so I used `Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)`. This way we show 12 month if the calendar have 12 months and we show 13 month if the calendar have 13 month.

Comment: Is this the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34207453/vb-net-combo-box-always-select-the-first-value/34207737#comment56160509_34207737 because I've tried and it work. But I want my code to make it simple like a loop. Is this possible.? or Not? Thank you. Appreciate your help

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't understand What you mean by "make it simple like a loop". Also you can use a for loop simply, but this way is more simple and with less codes. Also since it used display member and value member, you can simply use it in data binding.

Comment: @ Reza Aghaei. Thank you for helping me. Your code is quite new for me. But it runs. I just like to make it simple like what @Tim did. Again. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome :) Hope you find the answer useful :)